# Detect URL hash removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I'm using the hash in the url to navigate thru AJAX content on a page
Problem is when the user clicks back to a point where there is no hash my hash change routine is not fired

How can I detect when going from something like mysite.com#page1 to mysite.com

My function is this

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {...
```

Which never gets fired when clicking back to a non hash URL

Comment: When you assign assign to `window.location` and the URL doesn't have a hash, it reloads the page. So none of the event handlers run.

Comment: Uh? I'm not using window.location

Comment: Clicking on a link is the same. If it contains the same URL with a different hash, it just navigates to that hash and the hashchange event fires. If it contains a URL with no hash, it reloads the page.

Comment: I'm not reloading the page, I'm using ajax to serve different content based on the links they are clicking and changing the hash on the page so if the page is refreshed then the same content is loaded and not the default page. This is NOT jumping to content on the page based on the hash

Comment: How are you changing the hash on the page if you're not assigning to `window.location`? I think you need to post your code that changes the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to a URL that has no hash, it reloads the page from that URL rather than keeping the same page and triggering the `hashchange` event.

If you want to stay on the same page but with no hash, put `#` at the end of the URL:

```
mysite.com/#
```

Comment: See my reply to your same comment above. Can I post a link to the website here? Maybe that will make it clearer what I mean

Comment: See my reply to your reply above

Comment: Can I post a link to the website here? Maybe that will make it clearer what I mean

Comment: It would be better if you posted the code in the question. It needs to be clear for all future readers of the question.

Comment: The code won't make sense. look at https://onemovieavenue.com/movies/33-star-wars-episode-iv-a-new-hope - under comments click through the different pages then click back and it will go back until you hit the url with no hash. The code is in view source right at the bottom. I'm setting the hash based on the page or comment clicked

Comment: Why not? Just post the function that runs when you want to load different content into the page.

Comment: Posted the function in the opening question. $(window).on('hashchange', function() {... never fires when going from a url with an hash token to a url with no hash token using the back button

Comment: How are you detecting that they used the back button?

Comment: If they use the browser's built-in navigation to go to a URL with no hash, it's just like reloading the page.

Comment: I feel like I'm going in circles here - clicking the back button with an hash is not reloading the page - going from a url with an hash to a url without an hash does NOT reload the page

Comment: As far as the hashchange event is concerned, it's the same. The solution is to make your starting URL contain an empty hash at the end. Then when they use the back button, it will fire the event.

Comment: Already tried that and works fine but don't think its a good way to start, that's why I'm asking is there a way to detect the hash removal